# Deno.stat is not a function error when using deno deploy

Tags: typescript, deno, oak

I am having a problem deploying my deno code using deno deploy. The code works perfectly locally using deployctl but fails when deployed.

```
import { Application } from "./deps.ts";
const app = new Application();

// Send static content
app.use(async (context) => {
  await context.send({
    root: `${Deno.cwd()}/public`,
    index: "index.html",
  });
});

addEventListener("fetch", app.fetchEventHandler());
```

It is a simple server that serves static files from the public directory. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Which module is `Application` from?

Comment: would you please add the errors on deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the runtime API reference for Deno Deploy:

https://deno.com/deploy/docs/runtime-api/

Included in the description text at the top of the document is this:

> Deno Deploy Runtime helps you write web servers in TypeScript/JavaScript using the Web APIs. It's different from Deno but aims to have similar APIs where applicable.
>
> The following Web and Deno APIs are supported on Deno Deploy Runtime...

And it goes on to provide an exhaustive list of the available Deno and web APIs in Deploy.

Here's a link to the file system API reference:

https://deno.com/deploy/docs/runtime-fs/

Here's what's included at the time of writing this answer:

> Deno Deploy supports a limited set of file system APIs available in Deno. Your project should be linked to a GitHub repository in order to use these APIs. URL deployments do not support these APIs and will result in an exception when used.
>
> - `Deno.cwd`
> - `Deno.readDir`
> - `Deno.readFile`
> - `Deno.readTextFile`

If you read through the list, you'll notice that `Deno.stat` is not included. It is not among the available methods in Deno Deploy.